# iPad throws NSUnknownKeyException, but in iOS simulator the app works fine?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

In iOS simulator, there are few things which are working fin in simulator but when I test the same stuff in device its throwing some errors.

For instance:
I have table view controller, its loading fine in Simulator. I am using iOS 6 simulator.

The same table view controller showing error as:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EventsTableViewController 0x1fda25e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key indTableView.
```

Please clarify me.

Comment: What version of iOS is on the iPad?

Comment: Same as that of simulator 6.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)